# List of lists in scala changing particular elements

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, case

I am given a list of list made of integers. I have to override the toString method to print this list of lists in a particular format.

However, I also need to change every '1' element that is in the list into an 'a.

Comment: what returntype are you expecting? mixing ints and chars in a list seems odd.

Comment: the list of lists should be printed ( consisting of integers and an 'a')

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because you have removed your code from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember your `list` is a list of lists, so you need something like:

```
list.map(_.map { case 1 => "a"; case x => x})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot override a method for the Int class, but you create your own class which inherits from Int and use instances of that class instead.

Here is a way to make your code work. I used x.toString because this returns a List[List[String]]. If you omit it, you'll get a List[List[Any]] which contains strings and integers, rather than all strings.

```
list.map(_.map { case 1 => "a"; case x => x.toString } )
```